# Jquery skip last two rows from looping

Tags: jquery

I have a table where I would like to skip last two rows from the loop I have written the following which is skipping last row. Is there a way to do with jquery functions?

```
$("#emp tr").not(':last').each(function () { });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnSave").click(
    function() {
      var result = DisableClick();
      alert(result);
    }
  );
});

function DisableClick() {
  var status = false;
  $("#emp tr").not(':last').each(function() {
    var status = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
    if (status === 'Yes') {
      moduleCompleted = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return moduleCompleted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="emp" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last1</td>
    <td>Last1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a range of elements by index. You can use a negative index to count from the end.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnSave").click(
    function() {
      var result = DisableClick();
      alert(result);
    }
  );
});

function DisableClick() {
  var status = false;
  $("#emp tr").slice(0, -2).each(function() {
    var status = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
    if (status === 'Yes') {
      moduleCompleted = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return moduleCompleted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="emp" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last1</td>
    <td>Last1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btnSave">Save Click</button>
```

But rather than hard-coding indexes like this, I suggest you give a class to the rows you want to process and use that in the selector. Or split the table into separate `thead`, `tbody`, and `tfoot` sections, and then use `#emp tbody tr` to select the rows.